# Setting custom Bootstrap button colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

The Bootstrap button colors are defined thus in variables.less:

```
@btnPrimaryBackground:              @linkColor;
@btnPrimaryBackgroundHighlight:     spin(@btnPrimaryBackground, 20%);

@btnInfoBackground:                 #5bc0de;
@btnInfoBackgroundHighlight:        #2f96b4;

@btnSuccessBackground:              #62c462;
@btnSuccessBackgroundHighlight:     #51a351;

@btnWarningBackground:              lighten(@orange, 15%);
@btnWarningBackgroundHighlight:     @orange;

@btnDangerBackground:               #ee5f5b;
@btnDangerBackgroundHighlight:      #bd362f;

@btnInverseBackground:              #444;
@btnInverseBackgroundHighlight:     @grayDarker;
```

Is there some logic in the hex codes for *background* and *backgroundHighlight* (i.e. specific color differences between the hex codes) or have they been set arbritrarily based on someone's design perspective that they 'look good'?

Comment: These are simply based on the designers color choices.  If you have a specific color theme for your site then choose something that will fit nicely with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that it was set specifically by design. But you could use lighten() or darken() mixins with 5% or 10% values to set highlights. But the same way you could make the whole button from one color :)

Answer (score 1):

I took the relevant LESS code from Bootstrap's source to generate a `btn-purple` class. The gradient, etc are very similar to the default buttons. You just need to change `@backgroundColor` and `@backgroundColorHighlight` in the LESS code below to change the color.

```
// Gradient Bar Colors for buttons and alerts
.gradientBar(@primaryColor, @secondaryColor, @textColor: #fff, @textShadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)) {
    color: @textColor;
    text-shadow: @textShadow;
    #gradient > .vertical(@primaryColor, @secondaryColor);
    border-color: @secondaryColor @secondaryColor darken(@secondaryColor, 15%);
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1) rgba(0,0,0,.1) fadein(rgba(0,0,0,.1), 15%);
}

// Gradients
#gradient {
    .horizontal(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333) {
        background-color: @endColor;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor); // FF 3.6+
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(@startColor), to(@endColor)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @endColor); // Opera 11.10
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @startColor, @endColor); // Standard, IE10
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=1)",argb(@startColor),argb(@endColor))); // IE9 and down
    }
    .vertical(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333) {
        background-color: mix(@startColor, @endColor, 60%);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // FF 3.6+
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@startColor), to(@endColor)); // Safari 4+, Chrome 2+
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @endColor); // Opera 11.10
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, @startColor, @endColor); // Standard, IE10
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=0)",argb(@startColor),argb(@endColor))); // IE9 and down
    }
    .directional(@startColor: #555, @endColor: #333, @deg: 45deg) {
        background-color: @endColor;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@deg, @startColor, @endColor); // FF 3.6+
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@deg, @startColor, @endColor); // Safari 5.1+, Chrome 10+
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@deg, @startColor, @endColor); // Opera 11.10
        background-image: linear-gradient(@deg, @startColor, @endColor); // Standard, IE10
    }
    .horizontal-three-colors(@startColor: #00b3ee, @midColor: #7a43b6, @colorStop: 50%, @endColor: #c3325f) {
        background-color: mix(@midColor, @endColor, 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(left, linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@startColor), color-stop(@colorStop, @midColor), to(@endColor));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, @startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, @startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=0)",argb(@startColor),argb(@endColor))); // IE9 and down, gets no color-stop at all for proper fallback
    }

    .vertical-three-colors(@startColor: #00b3ee, @midColor: #7a43b6, @colorStop: 50%, @endColor: #c3325f) {
        background-color: mix(@midColor, @endColor, 80%);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@startColor), color-stop(@colorStop, @midColor), to(@endColor));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-image: linear-gradient(@startColor, @midColor @colorStop, @endColor);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='%d', endColorstr='%d', GradientType=0)",argb(@startColor),argb(@endColor))); // IE9 and down, gets no color-stop at all for proper fallback
    }
    .radial(@innerColor: #555, @outerColor: #333) {
        background-color: @outerColor;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0, center center, 460, from(@innerColor), to(@outerColor));
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, @innerColor, @outerColor);
        background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(circle, @innerColor, @outerColor);
        background-image: -o-radial-gradient(circle, @innerColor, @outerColor);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .striped(@color: #555, @angle: 45deg) {
        background-color: @color;
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 100%, 100% 0, color-stop(.25, rgba(255,255,255,.15)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255,255,255,.15)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255,255,255,.15)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(@angle, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(@angle, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(@angle, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
        background-image: linear-gradient(@angle, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    }
}
// Reset filters for IE
.reset-filter() {
    filter: e(%("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false)"));
}

.buttonBackground(@startColor, @endColor, @textColor: #fff, @textShadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25)) {
    // gradientBar will set the background to a pleasing blend of these, to support IE<=9
    .gradientBar(@startColor, @endColor, @textColor, @textShadow);
    *background-color: @endColor; /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
    .reset-filter();

      // in these cases the gradient won't cover the background, so we override
    &:hover, &:focus, &:active, &.active, &.disabled, &[disabled] {
        color: @textColor;
        background-color: @endColor;
        *background-color: darken(@endColor, 5%);
        background-position: 0 -15px;
    }

    // IE 7 + 8 can't handle box-shadow to show active, so we darken a bit ourselves
    &:active,
    &.active {
        background-color: darken(@endColor, 10%) e("\9");
    }
}

// Provide *some* extra contrast for those who can get it
.btn-purple.active {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

// Set the backgrounds
// -------------------------
@backgroundColor: lighten(#7a43b6, 10%);
@backgroundColorHighlight: darken(#7a43b6, 5%);
.btn-purple {
    .buttonBackground(@backgroundColor, @backgroundColorHighlight);
}
```

Comment: Yes!!  Thank you so much!  I desperately wanted to find a way to make a purple button that looked just like the default theme of Bootstrap!  This is exactly what i was looking for!